# Datanucleus/mongodb: Persisting map of lists

Tags: java, mongodb, jdo, datanucleus

I'm using datanucleus 3.2.5 / JDO for persisting objects to a MongoDB database.

While trying to persist one map of lists I'm getting the following exception:

```
RuntimeException: json can't serialize type [list element type here]
```

Some sample code:

```java
@PersistenceCapable
public class SomeClass {
    private Map<String, List<SomeOtherClass>> myAttribute;
    // ...
}


@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly="true")
public class SomeOtherClass {
    private String attribute;
    // ...
}
```

I could get around this problem annotating the embedded attribute as `@Serialized`, but I would rather prefer a more elegant way.

Am I missing anything? Is there a better approach to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Andy's [reply](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7563_lastpage,yes#37018) to my question in the DataNucleus forums:

> No persistence spec defines any support for a container of a container. You are always recommended to make the inner container (List in your case) a field of an intermediate class.

So there are two approaches here:

## Use an intermediate class

By far the most elegant and maintainable solution. Following the example toy code:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class SomeClass {
    private Map<String, SomeOtherClassContainer> myAttribute;
    // ...
}

@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly="true")
public class SomeClassContainer {
    private List<SomeOtherClass> myAttribute;
    // ...
}

@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly="true")
public class SomeOtherClass {
    private String attribute;
    // ...
}
```

## Mark the attribute as @Serializable

Ugly and probably a source of headaches, specially if relying on [java default serialization](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45).

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class SomeClass {
    @Serializable
    private Map<String, List<SomeOtherClass>> myAttribute;
    // ...
}

@PersistenceCapable(embeddedOnly="true")
public class SomeOtherClass implements Serializable {
    private String attribute;
    // ...
}
```